# Overscroll not working right way and div not displaying whole.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have a div that is supposed to be the black part of this image: 
[image]

but the div is the white stripe on the top part of the window instead. and when i enter a command and something pops up, the div expands as i go. like this: 
[image]

i have overflow:scroll on the div as css, but after i enter enough commands, the overflow doesn't work as it should, like this: 
[image]

it expands below the footer and where i enter my command (the white stripe on the bottom.)

so my question is how do i make the div as big as the black part and how to fix the overflow problem (the extra text only shows above the footer and where i enter commands.  here is my code:
`here`https://jsfiddle.net/qb5xaw3c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `flex`

```
body { display: flex; }
#targetDiv { flex-glow: 90; overflow: auto; }
footer { flex-glow: 10; }
```

Cannot test without exact JavaScript, here is the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/qb5xaw3c/1/

The problem is that you didn't define any height for `body` or `#main`, and if you do so, you should use `overflow: auto;` to allow the browser decide show the scroll bar or not. Also I don't think make a `.main` for footer is a good idea (semantics matter)

### Edit 1 -

Sorry it shouldn't use the `flex`, just a simple `calc` would solve it

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height: 100vh; }
footer { height: 100px; }
#targetDiv { height: calc(100vh - 100px - 30px); }
```

Try: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/3g88ugzd/1/

You still have to define the height of `#targetDiv` explicitly to make the `overflow` happens. It is not working with `%` height.

Comment: it didn't change, here's the whole thing though since you need it. sry i didn't know: https://jsfiddle.net/3g88ugzd/

Comment: when i enter a new command when there is a scroll bar, the result pops up under the previous command, meaning the user gotta manually scroll down to see the new result for the command he just typed. how do i fix this?

Comment: You could study on the `scrollTop` of jQuery which you may want to apply after each output complete that means scroll the `div` to the bottom after each command printed